# How can I make a GUI for my C++ code using Qt?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt

I have some C++ code which acts like a mini search engine and I would like to make a GUI for it.

What additional code will I need to add in order to do this?

My program currently has three source files:

1. test.cpp
2. linkedlist.h
3. table.h

Comment: Stating the names of your files without stating their content is not exactly useful.

Answer (score 7):

Download Qt Creator and follow along with the bundled tutorials until you get a good understanding of how it works. Then apply that knowledge to your project and see if you can get it to work. If you come across a more specific problem, come back to SO and we will be glad to help you.

Comment: Yes. If you're using Windows, you can download the whole Qt SDK which is a great way to get started.  It includes Qt Creator, the Qt dev libraries, and compilers.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at a `Qt` tutorial.

This [one](http://gautam-m.blogspot.com/2008/08/qt-simple-example.html) is simple enough, or you can take a look at the [official ones](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/examples.html); you should understand them quickly. If you don't, feel free to ask what was unclear.

However, just a few remarks about your question:

Your question, as it is written know is really vague. It suggests that:

- We guess what kind of GUI you want
- We write all the GUI code for you

You really should rewrite this and show us what you already tried...